# Method called before killing app - Cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova

Is there a method that is called before app is killed in Cordova? I find out there is `onPause/onResume`. But it works only when app is put to background: [cordova doc](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#pause). 
I have service, that i want to start only once in first visit of page. But when i keep visiting that page, that service start multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't any event that fires before cordova app is killed.
But what you want to do is quite simple using `localStorage`

```
//you can use the following inside document.ready() or cordova's deviceready

if (localStorage["firstTimeFlag"] == null || localStorage["firstTimeFlag"] == "") 
{
  alert("You are here for the first time");
  //here add your service,do your thing. show start tour or splash screen or something like that
  window.localStorage["firstTimeFlag"] = true;
} else {
  alert("You are not here for the first time");
}
```

Comment: That would be good, but after killing app i want localStorage["firstTimeFlag"] to be null again

Comment: then use sessionStorage instead of localStorage.